# Does purging an application prevent its reinstallation?

Tags: apt, purge

If I'm using purge to remove something, will I be able to reinstall that thing after if I want or it's somehow blocks that option in the future?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! [This answer] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies/142808#142808) will answer pretty much any question about apt.

Comment: Visit manapage `man apt-get`. purge doesn't block any installation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You will be able** to install the software again in the future.

**purge**, except from the application files, removes the configuration files used by that  application as well.

Answer (score 1):

You will be able to install it normally. The only difference between `purge` and regular `remove` is that `purge` destroys your settings. So if you reinstall, your previous settings will be lost.